# How to install ecCodes in Anaconda

Tags: powershell, anaconda, miniconda, eccodes

I tried to install ecCodes with Anaconda. After several failed attempts, it seemed to have worked, as i didnt get an error report in the terminal. As you can see in the Screenshot.

The process froze several times with this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge eccodes
```

so i used this one for installaion:

```
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/broken" eccodes
```

[image: Screenshot of the Terminal after installation of ecCodes]

If i try to search ecCodes now with the command: >conda search eccodes
it can't find any matches.
Could someone tell me how i can test if ecCodes is succesfully installed? Or can someone tell by the screenshot if something went wrong while installing?

[image: Screenshot of searchresults]

I tred different ways of searching for the programm but can't seem to find the right syntax. I also tried to find the package directory by navigating through folders, but this seems quite hopeless and i tried to find commands that i could run, which should get executed by ecCodes incase it is instaled, but i also couldn't find any hints on that.
The Script that i have been working on, which is supposed to pull Data from a website and which should run, with ecCodes installed (following the online documentation of th Script), still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used this one for installaion:
>
> `conda install -c "conda-forge/label/broken" eccodes`

Oh no! Normal users should never use the `broken` label - it's literally where broken packages are sent to keep them from being installed.

#### Rollback changes

First, I would strongly recommend rolling back your changes.

```bash
## inspect your revisions
## find the "n" before there were any "broken" packages
conda list --revisions

## roll back to that revision 
conda install --revision n
```

### Likely issue

The issue you are encountering (slow solve) is likely that you have a **base** Anaconda installation, and then when you add the `conda-forge` channel, it leads to the solver trying to reinstall every package you have using Conda Forge instead of Anaconda. That is a huge computational problem to solve and so it takes a long time. Even the faster solver in Mamba will struggle with the task.

### Create fresh environment

Despite the Anaconda documentation that implies one can easily install packages from other channels, in practice it is almost always problematic. Instead, I generally recommend that anyone with an Anaconda installation that needs Conda Forge packages, they should create a new environment that uses only Conda Forge. For example,

```
## "foo" below is arbitrary - pick a name you like
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3.10 eccodes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I reverted Anaconda to the first time installed and will try again.